# Can Someone Explain the Continuity and Death Infinity Stones Recently Introduced?

Tags: marvel, comics, infinity-stones

I was doing some internet surfing the other day, and realized that there are now 8 Infinity Stones (I think they're called Infinity Gems in the comics): Power, Space, Mind, Soul, Reality, Time, Death, and Continuity. Now, I know about the first six (Power, Space, Mind, Soul, Reality, & Time) due to the movies in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). However, I don't know much about the Death Gem and all I know about the Continuity Gem is that it was apparently revealed in a Deadpool book.

Can someone explain to me what these two Gems are and what they do, their purpose?

Comment: https://www.quirkybyte.com/blog/2018/04/infinity-stones-marvel-comics/

Comment: Interesting. Do you have enough information about the two Stones to post as an answer?

Comment: Nope. Just googled it. Took me ten seconds

Comment: If you could gather just a little bit more info, I would be more than happy to accept as an answer.

Comment: To be honest I'm not especially au fait with either Deadpool or Infinity Gauntlet 2015. If you've read the article you're already ahead of me.

Comment: @Valorum that looks like a pretty bad source. Poor grammar, and using pictures of clearly six stones to illustrate the existence of eight.

Comment: @OrangeDog - I look forward to you posting an amazing answer with quotes, references and comic panels :-)

Comment: In the Ultimate Universe (Earth-1610), there are indeed 8 Infinity Stones, and 2 Infinity Gauntlets (holding 4 stones each). See [10 Other Infinity Stones From Marvel Comics We Bet You Never Knew](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.quirkybyte.com/blog/2018/04/infinity-stones-marvel-comics/amp/), which mentions the Death and Continuity stones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Continuity Gem has only appeared once in *Deadpool Vol. 3* Issue 27, and even then only in the "Continuity Spontinuity" storyline. In it Deadpool finds the Gem which has the power to retcon Marvel comics history and also talk to the writers apparently.

[image: Deadpool acquires the Continuity Gem] [image: Deadpool starts using the Gem]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Deadpool throws the Gem away at the end of the storyline and it hasn't been seen since.

[image: Deadpool throws away the Gem]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

The Death Stone has appeared a whole 2 times! It first appears in *Infinity Gauntlet Vol. 2* Issue 5 where Anwen Bakian creates it by using the Reality Gem. She then gives it to Thanos who puts it in his Infinity Gauntlet. However, the Stone starts to corrupt him and he is eventually turned to dust.

[image: Thanos receives the Death Stone which kills him] [image: Thanos is turned to dust]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

An alternate version of the Death Stone appears in the *Marvel Contest of Champions* game.

---

It's also worth noting that in some other Marvel universes there are even more Infinity Gems - it just depends on the universe really. There are such things as the Ego Gem and one universe with 8 Gems and 2 Gauntlets etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Continuity Stone is an Infinity Stone that could only find place in the Deadpool story arcs. In a certain issue, Deadpool gets his hands on the Continuity Stone, which gives the characters the powers to talk to the comic book writers themselves. The Picture above shows Deadpool engaging in a conversation with the writers. Safe to say we did not see that in Infinity War.

Comment: You refer to a picture, but looks like you have forgotten to attach it. Could you do it so that it improves the answer?

Comment: If you could add the picture you mentioned, I would be more than glad to accept this answer. Also, any info on the Death Stone?

Comment: Please cite your sources in the future: https://www.quirkybyte.com/blog/2018/04/infinity-stones-marvel-comics/

Answer (score 0):

The death stone was created by the reality stone to trick Thanos, it is not as powerful as the others. The continuity stone allows you to speak directly to people in the real world. It’s origins are a mystery, but probably to be revealed.

Comment: As has been said on a lot of your answers could you edit in some evidence to back this up?

Comment: Just to be clear: of your last eight posts, seven have been downvoted and one has been deleted. I appreciate your enthusiasm, but at this rate, you're going to trigger an automated answer ban. Please work on the quality of your answers: better sources, more detailed explanations. This is a friendly warning. It's all I can do. The rest is on you.

Comment: Are you saying that this is one of those questions? I think it's pretty clear what's being asked

Answer (score 0):

The Continuity Gem affects continuity. It can rewrite the comics as well as other things.

The Death Stone? Well, it probably controls death.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It doesn't explain very much to say that they affect the thing they're named after; the question was asking for an explanation of how they fit into (some of) the Marvel universe, and what their *purpose* (not just their action) is.

Comment: You have a nice start with how the Continuity Gem works but you should expand on that a bit more and provide evidence for it. If you don't know how the Death Stone work and what it is you are better off just using a partial answer here instead, instead of what you currently have written.